# error : Element <DebugInformationFormat> has an invalid value of "None"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmusphinx

I am building C++ projects in solution of **Sphinxbase**, on compiling through visual studio 2010 following error appears

Error   1   error : Element  has an invalid value of "None".    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets   153 6   sphinxbase

I am able to settle other issues but solution to this error could not found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which sphinxbase version are you trying to compile but you need to use latest version which you can checkout from github

http://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase

Comment: I downloaded the .zip file from [sphinxbase-5prealpha](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxbase/5prealpha) as described in the [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam). .gz file had an issue that the project `\sphinxbase\win32\sphinx_seg\sphinx_seg.vcxproj` could not loaded in visual studio.

Comment: I have updated the archive, it was missing required file. Please download it and try again

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem when started use VS2010 compiller instead VS2012
I decided this error with deleting value "None" from
Project Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2zvQ.png)